# Create a pivot with 3 variables in R

Tags: r, group-by, pivot

I have three variables in one dataframe:

```
Country <- ("ARG","BR","US","ARG","ARG","BR","CH")
Education_level <- ("HIGH","COLLEGE","KINDER","KINDER","COLLEGE")
Indicator <- (1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1)
```

I Need to create a pivot or some groupby counting or summarising the values of "Indicator" grouped by Country and Education_level. How can I do that?

Comment: Your vectors have different length

Comment: I filled Indicator with more values, but all the vectors have the same lenght.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Indicator ~ Country + Education_level)
```

Comment: Do you know how can I create a new variable with the percents for each Country + Education_level? Thanks!

Comment: @AgusDam87 you can use `prop.table`